# global attributes storing text data

Tags: javascript, html

I commonly use `id` or `class` to pass some parameters to a javascript function. For example:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onclick="callInput(this.id)">
```

However, in some cases, elements  already have `id` and `class`, so I'm gonna need another attribute to store parameters.

Which attributes are appropriate for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use data attribute

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onclick="callInput(this.id)" data-id="someid" >
```

You can use anything along with data-

Example data-anything="something"

Read more about data attribute from [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

To read the data attribute through jquery you can use

```
$('#myInput').on("click",function(){
    alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

or

```
$('#myInput').on("click",function(){
    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

Comment: can you explain more about this `data` attribute? Why does `this.id`  take `someid` instead of `myInput`? Does `data-class`, `data-title`, `data-placeholder`,... exist?